# Does MonoTouch work on a virtualized Mac OS?

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, virtualbox

Is it possible to install it on VirtualBox or other virtualization solution? If yes, how fast it works?

Comment: In a virtualized OS you can run everything that can run in not virualized box. The Problem would be to virtualize OS X. You can install a vrtuaized version of OSX Server in VMWare or Paralles, I don't know about about virtual box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem running MonoTouch frameworks/IDEs in a virtualized Mac.

I can expect a lot of problems transferring across the USB cable the compiled applications to a real iPhone/iPad to test it. iTunes and XCode tend to be very picky about the configurations.

Buying a cheapest Mac might be easier and less costly if you consider the time you might waste, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation version of MonoTouch will run, but the SDK tools used on the production version wont.

Answer (score 3):

We were able to develop and deploy apps to real devices under VMWare Player and WMWare workstation.  The problem we have is MonoTouch activations.  It would activate and randomly need reactivation.  It would work for a while then it would fail to activate.

Each time it failed we would need to contact support and reset the key so we could continue working.  They do not support virtualized hardware and do not plan to fix the activation issue.

In the end we purchased real hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Via VMWare Workstation I have it running quite nicely. Installing apps to iOS devices is fine, but creating a network for softdebug to find the iphone (or vice versa) is the only problem I've seen.

I'm trying to figure that out right now - I'll try and update this thread with the solution.